# Query Failure on Rails Postgresql Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, indexing

I have experienced an interesting issue with postgresql indexes in my application, that uses Rails 4 and Postgresql. Basically, I have a project table and an invitations table.

Invitation has a foreign key project_id and a foreign key user_id.

I have a project with the id number 770,

```
  Invitation.find(761816).project_id # 770
  Invitation.find(761816).user_id # 389
```

However, the query that searches for this project based on user_id fails.

```
  Invitation.where(project_id: 770, user_id: 389) #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Of course, Invitation belongs_to User, belongs_to Project and User has_many Invitations. The same query works for any other invitation object I could find.

These attributes on the invitation table are indexed, which could be the reason for this behavior:

```
  add_index :invitations, :user_id
  add_index :invitations, :project_id
```

This is the first time I experienced this issue in a pretty large database that has been operating for more than a year now.

I would appreciate it if someone could give me some advice on why this is happening and what could be done to fix this problem, or how postgres indexes can be rebuilt in case there is a reason to rebuild them.

**Update**

Here are the results of queries I have been asked to execute:

```
Invitation.count # 787322
Invitation.first.inspect # "#<Invitation id: 13, ... user_id: 358, ... project_id: 14, status: 5, followup_status: 0 ...>"
Invitation.first.project_id.class.name # Fixnum
Invitation.first.user_id.class.name # Fixnum
Invitation.where(project_id:770).count # 353
Invitation.where(user_id:389).count # 775
Invitation.where(project_id:770,user_id:389).count # 0
```

and the most interesting part:

```
Invitation.where(project_id:770,user_id:389,id:761816).count # 1
```

**Update 2**

Here are the explain statements of these two problem queries:

```
Invitation.where(project_id:770,user_id:389)

-------------------------------
Bitmap Heap Scan on invitations  (cost=45.18..49.20 rows=1 width=192)
Recheck Cond: ((user_id = 389) AND (project_id = 770))
->  BitmapAnd  (cost=45.18..45.18 rows=1 width=0)
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_invitations_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..22.36 rows=792 width=0)
           Index Cond: (user_id = 389)
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_invitations_on_project_id  (cost=0.00..22.57 rows=819 width=0)
           Index Cond: (project_id = 770)
(7 rows)
```

and the second correct one:

```
Invitation.where(project_id:770,user_id:389,id:761816)

----------------------
Index Scan using invitations_pkey on invitations  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=192)
Index Cond: (id = 761816)
Filter: ((project_id = 770) AND (user_id = 389))
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Some more interesting information, just tried making a backup and running the data on another machine, everything works fine! Only the production machine displays this behavior.

Comment: Did you try to recreated indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a problem with a corrupt index then it would be easy to diagnose -- drop the indexes and retry the query.

I assume that the generated query is correct?

It doesn't look like a very natural way to be using Rails, btw. Maybe:

```
@user.projects.find_by(:id => 770)
```

Comment: When I am looking up by Id and don't care about error being thrown (or want an error to be thrown) I use simple find(id). The interesting thing is that it gives the same error even on pure sql statements in where or find_by_sql. I will try dropping and rebuilding the indexes for these tables.

Comment: I would try the query without indexes as well before recreating them.

Comment: I just finished the deployment on production machine. After dropping and rebuilding the indexes the problem stopped and Invitation was indexed correctly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hurrah! Stupid indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's log our results here.

### Step 1.

```
Invitation.find 761816 # => #<Invitation id: 761816, ... user_id: 389, ... project_id: 770, status: 6, ....>
Invitation.where(project_id: 770, user_id: 389) # => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

### Step 2. Explains

```
Invitation.where(project_id: 770, user_id: 389).explain
```

gives

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on invitations (cost=45.93..49.94 rows=1 width=193)
Recheck Cond: ((project_id = 770) AND (user_id = 389))
-> BitmapAnd (cost=45.93..45.93 rows=1 width=0)
-> Bitmap Index Scan on index_invitations_on_project_id (cost=0.00..22.72 rows=839 width=0)
Index Cond: (project_id = 770)
-> Bitmap Index Scan on index_invitations_on_user_id (cost=0.00..22.96 rows=871 width=0)
Index Cond: (user_id = 389)
(7 rows)
```

and

```
Invitation.where(id: 761816).explain
```

gives

```
Index Scan using invitations_pkey on invitations (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=193)
Index Cond: (id = 761816)
(2 rows)
```

### Step 3. Different queries

Can you please give results for these queries?

```
Invitation.count
Invitation.first.inspect
Invitation.first.project_id.class.name
Invitation.first.user_id.class.name
Invitation.where(project_id:770).count
Invitation.where(user_id:389).count
Invitation.where(project_id:770,user_id:389).count
```

## Step 4. Different checks

Just to be sure, can we check the following?

1. Compare LC_COLLATE setting for production/dev machine (low chance, it affecting anything, but still interesting to know)
2. Run step #3 queries in database. We will at least know is the problem is related to Rails or Postgres.
3. Is it possible to drop (and recreate later) indexes in production database? Just to see how query behaves when indexes were removed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make the testview on the production machine at the moment, and on local machine with the actual database dump the query works perfectly fine. I can give the output I get from the production console: first one:

Comment: "#<Invitation id: 761816, ... user_id: 389, ... project_id: 770, status: 6, ....>

Comment: Second one: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: And what are outputs of `Invitation.where(project_id: 770, user_id: 389).explain` and `Invitation.where(id: 761816 ).explain` ?

Comment: Bitmap Heap Scan on invitations  (cost=45.93..49.94 rows=1 width=193)
   Recheck Cond: ((project_id = 770) AND (user_id = 389))
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=45.93..45.93 rows=1 width=0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_invitations_on_project_id  (cost=0.00..22.72 rows=839 width=0)
               Index Cond: (project_id = 770)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_invitations_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..22.96 rows=871 width=0)
               Index Cond: (user_id = 389) (7 rows)

Comment: Index Scan using invitations_pkey on invitations  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=193)
   Index Cond: (id = 761816)
(2 rows)

Comment: @VitalyStanchits it's really tough question. Can you please execute queries given in Step #3 (which I've added in answer body). Please add them into the post and then add comment here to let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I have upddated the start post with the given queries.

Comment: @VitalyStanchits can you check step #4, please :)

Comment: Ok, with the next production deploy I will make a migration that kills all the invitation table indexes and builds them again. Remove index and then add index. I will tell you the results once I'm done.

Comment: What queries give from database w(without Rails)

Comment: The problem was solved after making a migration that drops and creates database indexes again. It appears to have been a database indexation error. Made a test to make sure I know when the problem occurs in the future.